# Puppeteer - Grabbing Distance from Hotel Website

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

**Problem:** I cannot grab the distance (kilometers or miles - depending on where you live), e.g. `25.9`.

[Wyndham hotel website](https://www.wyndhamhotels.com/hotels/chicago-il-usa?brand_id=HR&checkInDate=10/31/2023&checkOutDate=11/5/2023&useWRPoints=false&children=0&adults=1&rooms=1&loc=ChIJ7cv00DwsDogRAMDACa2m4K8&sessionId=1695168565)

I either grab a whole bunch of text that is not consistent or I grab empty list.

[image]

Things I've tried:

```
// returns empty list
// page.$$eval('div[class^="cmp-property-card"] p[class="hotel-address"] span.hotel-address-text + span', elements => elements.map(el => el.textContent.trim()))
        
// returns empty list
// page.$$eval('div[class^="cmp-property-card"] p[class="hotel-address"] span:nth-child(0) + span', elements => elements.map(el => el.textContent.trim()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distance texts can be grabbed from upper spans by xpath expression.

Root element is smth like `//*[@class=\'hotel-details-sec\']`.

Units element is inner span that contains class part `distance-` and doesn't have property `display: none` (it can be Miles or Kilometers).

*I defined that displayed property condition in xpath, however, it's bad implementation, it's better to filter elements by visibility (I'm just lazy)*

Distance is inner span that is preceding from span with class `distance-text`.

So, you should wait for at least one container with data to exist, get two elements arrays and map them via `$$eval` and then construct distance string.

```js
    await page.waitForSelector('.hotel-details-sec');
    const units = await page.$$eval('xpath///*[@class=\'hotel-details-sec\']//span[contains(@class,"distance-") and not(contains(@style,\'display: none\'))]', elements => elements.map(el => el.textContent))
    const distances = await page.$$eval('xpath///*[@class=\'hotel-details-sec\']//span[@class="distance-text"]/preceding-sibling::span', elements => elements.map(el => el.textContent))
    const distanceStrings = units.map((u, i) => `${distances[i]} ${u}`);
```

Second variant of implementation which can handle cases when containers are rendered, but their data is not:

```js
    await page.waitForSelector('.hotel-details-sec');
    const distanceStrings: string[] = []
    const details = await page.$$('.hotel-details-sec .search-results-property-info');
    for (const card of details) {
      const distance = await card.waitForSelector('xpath///span[@class="distance-text"]/preceding-sibling::span');
      const units = await card.waitForSelector("xpath///span[contains(@class,'distance-') and not(contains(@style,'display: none'))]");
      const distanceString = await page.evaluate((d, u) => `${d['innerText']} ${u['innerText']}`, distance!, units!);
      distanceStrings.push(distanceString);
    }
```

Comment: To use XPath, instead of `page.$$eval()` use `page.$x()`. It returns an array by default.

Answer (score 0):

##### With this precise `XPath` selector:

```
const selector = '//span[text()="Kilometers"]/preceding-sibling::span';
await page.waitForXPath(selector);
# in realLife©®™, use a for loop:
var [km] = await page.$x(selector);
km = await km.getProperty('textContent');
km = await km.jsonValue();
console.log(`${km}KM`);
```

##### Output

```
25.9KM
```

Comment: running     ```var km = page.$x('//span[text()="Kilometers"]/preceding-sibling::span')[0];
    km = await km.jsonValue();
    km = await km.getProperty('textContent');
    console.log("km is: ", km);``` gave me `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'jsonValue')`

Comment: Missed `await`, post edited accordingly

Comment: The updated code still returns `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'jsonValue')`

Comment: Forget code, and use the `XPath`. If you had added your code from your original post, I will able to test. That's required when you post a question. Tested OK in a browser

Comment: `pptr` tested OK, see my edited post